# PHP: Simple way to convert "Oct 24, 2011" date to "2011-10-24"?

Tags: php

I need to convert **Oct 24, 2011 03:16 PM** to **2011-10-24 15:16:00** in php.

I know its possible by creating a variable for each month "$jan = 01, $feb = 02, etc" and then using "explode" to split the information by space and re-arranging it in the correct order.

But is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: Please search before you post, a search for "php convert date" would find many results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strtotime()` is a very powerful date parser.  Use it to get a UNIX timestamp of the incoming date, and use the `date()` function to output the date in your desired format.

```
<?php

$ts = strtotime("Oct 24, 2011 03:16 PM");
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ts);

?>
```

Comment: Please mark your question answered for future Googlers :).

Answer (score 3):

```
$string_date = strtotime("Oct 24, 2011");

$date_object = strtotime($string_date);

$formatted = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $date_object);
```

Check out the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for more formatting options.

Comment: Also, [strtotime()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Oct 24, 2011 03:16 PM"));
```

Answer (score 1):

date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime ("Oct 24, 2011 03:16 PM" ) );

Answer (score 0):

The strtotime() option mentioned in other answers here is the easiest method, but don't fall in love with the function for ALL date string->number conversions. It can and WILL screw up at some point. If you know exactly what format a date string will be in, then use the more reliable

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M j\, Y', "Oct 24,2011");
```